# How can I refresh the entire table sorting cache after dynamic table update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm using JoeQuery's [Stupid-Table](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin#stupid-jquery-table-sort) jQuery plugin to sort a simple table. I do not know how to refresh the entire sort cache on a dynamic table.

The `updateSortVal` function allows one to update a single cell. For example:

```
$age_td.updateSortVal(23);
```

But how can I refresh the entire table when the entire `thead` and `tbody` is replaced?

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        $("#myTable thead, #myTable tbody").empty();
        if (data.data.length > 0) {
            var $thead_tr;
            var $tbody_tr;
            for (var r = 0; r < data.data.length; r++) {
                if (r == 0) $thead_tr = $("<tr>").appendTo("#myTable thead");
                    $tbody_tr = $("<tr>").appendTo("#myTable tbody");
                    for (var c in data.data[r]) {
                        if (r == 0) $("<th>").html(c).appendTo($thead_tr);
                        $("<td>").html(data.data[r][c]).appendTo($tbody_tr);
                        // I've tried adding `.updateSortVal(data.data[r][c]);`
                        // to the above as well, but the cache for the `th`
                        // needs to be re-cached as well, so let's do it all at once
                    }
                }
                // I'd like to refresh the entire stupidtable cache here
                $("#myTable").stupidtable().show();
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should basically remove your table instead of emptying it, and then recreating it to reset suitable (width replaceWith() for example)

```
$("#myTable").replaceWith('<table id="myTable"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
```

instead of

```
$("#myTable thead, #myTable tbody").empty();
```

**EDIT**

As I am not sure about what you call cache, I did this fiddle.
Can you check it and explain me if you reproduce your problem ?

[**Fiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dw21vosn/)

Comment: Good idea. But it didn't refresh the cache. I know this is difficult without a jsfiddle. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Ryan Nope, copy/pasted. Give me your modified code so as I can check if I see where the problem come from

Comment: No, I didn't edit stupid table either. But yours works like a charm, so I'm looking to duplicate in my code.