# How can I unbind a jQuery plugin from an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using JoeQuery's [Stupid-Table](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin#stupid-jquery-table-sort) jQuery plugin to sort a simple table. I do not know how to refresh the entire sort cache on a dynamic table.

It works like this:

```
$("#myTable").stupidtable();
```

But I'd like to unbind the plugin from this object and re-bind it so I can reset the sorting to use the values from a new, dynamically generated, table.

How can I detach or unbind this plugin from this object?

```
$("#myTable").stupidtable();
// do some ajax stuff that rebuilds #myTable
// $("#myTable").stupidtable('destroy');
//                               ^--- something like this, but this plugin
//                                    does not have a destroy method
$("#myTable").stupidtable();
```

What do you recommend?

Here's a link to the [stupidtable.js](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin/blob/master/stupidtable.js).

Comment: Unless the plugin has some sort of destroy functionality, you can't.

Comment: Usually jQuery plugins include a `destroy` method which will remove whatever the plugin has attached to the DOM; this one doesn't appear to have that.

Comment: alas, no such method for `stupidtable()`

Comment: Hey there! I've been out of the jQuery loop for a while unfortunately. Can someone point me to an example of this .destroy() convention so I can apply it to stupidtable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The plugin only binds a namespaced click event. I guess you basically have to use .off() on the click.stupidtable event.

```
$("#myTable").off("click.stupidtable");
```

EDIT: the selector above was wrong sorry

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't refresh the sorting cache. Thanks for trying. I know it's difficult without a jsfiddle.

Comment: I edited my answer because the selector for the .off() was wrong. I'm looking for your cache problem

Comment: See my edited answer on your other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701630/how-can-i-refresh-the-entire-table-sorting-cache-after-dynamic-table-update/28702350#28702350